# Sync between two devices without Internet connection: Is it possible?

Tags: android, mobile

My coursework requirement is to build an Android application that lists all available mobile devices within close proximity. None of the devices have access to the internet.

To make things easier, the assumption is that all devices have my application installed.

When user first installs my app, they must define a user name and upload a profile picture.

When they launch my app, it should display the following profile info about other devices nearby:

- User Name Profile picture

Now, I know this is an open ended question, but I'm totally stumped and need some guidance.

Specifically, I find these points challenging:

How to establish communication between devices/my app without internet?
How to retrieve other devices' profile picture without having to store everything locally on the device
I did some research and found Wi-Fi Peer to Peer, but not sure if this will be suitable for my use case as I don't have internet access. Bluetooth is another option but I think devices would have to be paired first before exchanging data.

Answer (score 1):

You can starting Wifi hotspot  with name like "YourAppName".
And create simple brodcasting this data inside this network.
So:

1. user opens your app and registering;
2. your application, checks if there is WIFI  "YourAppName".
3. if NO, your app start hot spot  "YourAppName".
4. if YES, your app promt user to connect to this network.
5. If connection successfully established, you will need to think how to transmit the list of data to your app, and represent it to user

Hope that this steps will helps you! Good luck